# Server Error in / Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't seem to get this to work on my local server but I'm able to run my project on other servers just fine. I am not sure why I can't get it to run locally.

System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context

[HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
   System.Web.HttpContext.get_Request() +12741358
   Sitecore.Security.Authentication.FormsAuthenticationHelper.GetCurrentUser() +134
   Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveUser() +24
   Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.ItemAccess.IsAllowed(Item item, AccessRight accessRight) +39
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.ApplySecurity(Item item, SecurityCheck securityCheck) +113
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database) +257
   Sitecore.Data.TemplateRecords.GetTemplate(ID templateID, Language language) +168
   Sitecore.Sharedsource.Tasks.TemplateConfigurationBuilder.Create(Database database, XmlNode configNode) +386
   Sitecore.Sharedsource.Tasks.NewsMover.AddTemplateConfiguration(XmlNode configNode) +69

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +193
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[] properties) +832
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +759
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +296
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.Add(String eventName, XmlNode configNode) +235
   Sitecore.Events.Event.GetConfigSubscribers() +379
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +373
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.Sql.SqlDataProvider.SetProperty(String parameterName, String value, CallContext context) +313
   Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.SetProperty(String name, String value, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers) +138
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexDatabasePropertyStore.Set(String key, String value) +229

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +76
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +193
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[] properties) +832
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +759
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +296
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +666
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager.get_SearchConfiguration() +261
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager.get_Cores() +77
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorSolrStartUp.Initialize() +57

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12962661
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12979668
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12819261

Comment: Stack seems to suggest that you are looking for the current user, is this sitecore? Suggest opening a support ticket with them. User context may not be available if the authentication mode is anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

May or may not help, but [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this exception will be thrown if your web application is running under IIS 7 in Integrated mode. Are you aware if that's the case?

Edit: Reading further it seems it's a combination of IIS 7 in integrated mode, plus accessing a request object from a method that was eventually called by Application_Start